# Absolute path in requirejs

Tags: requirejs, mustache

I'm using requirejs with mustache templates like this

```
define(['text!templates/popups.html','text!templates/buildqueue.html','mustache'], function (popups,buildqueue,Mustache) {});
```

I have a folder stucture like this

```
script/templates/templates/popups.html
```

When I'm in production mode the folder structure is

```
prod/script/templates/templates/popups.html
```

I want the templates folder to be outside of the scriptfolder like.

```
/templates
/script
/prod/script
```

I can reference the path as text!../templates/templates/popups.html but as soon as I'm in prod mode the ../ is wrong.

How do I make a url to the templates folder that works when it is referenced to in script/ and prod/script ?

Comment: Your question starts with a sharp distinction between the file tree in development versus the one in production but as your question unfolds this distinction is blurred to the point that it is hard to know what you expect to be where exactly.

Comment: I updated the question I hope it is more clear now. Basically I want to be able to move the templates folder ouside of the script folder and keep the same url in the requirejs modules.